# jsTree, need to expand all the nodes when refreshing

Tags: java, jquery, json, jstree

I'm trying to expand all the nodes in my JSTree after refreshing it but without success.

```
 $('#'+messages.Instance_Name).jstree(true).settings.core.data = interfaceNode;
 $('#'+messages.Instance_Name).jstree(true).refresh();
```

Here is my data :

```
{
   "TANGO":{
      "status":2,
      "message":"TANGO dklfjklsdfjsdklfjdklfjasdklfj !!"
   },
   "AQS1":{
      "status":1,
      "message":"message AQS1",
      "sub AQS1":{
         "status":2,
         "sub sub AQS1":{
            "status":2
         }
      },
      "sub AQS2":{
         "status":3
      }
   }
}
```

The node AQS1 is not expanded.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4):

this was missing on my .jstree when creating my tree at the first time

```
.bind("refresh.jstree", function (e, data) 
    { $(this).jstree("open_all");})
```

:-)